# spring-boot 2 and liquibase: config in application yml ignored

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I try to migrate an app from spring-boot1 to spring-boot 2, but I have a lot of difficulty with the spring-boot part:

I have this log:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configurati

with this yaml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: xxx
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: false
  liquibase:
      change-log: "classpath:/liquibase/xxx-db/db.changelog.json"

  datasource:
    platform: oracle
```

liquibase and spring-boot 2 seem ignore the liquibase part of my application.yml
any idea?

my pom:

```
    <spring-boot.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    <liquibase.version>3.4.2</liquibase.version>
```

Comment: I've never put quotes around a yml property. Is there a reason you've done so?

Comment: I don´t think the liquid base property should be inside the spring , I would also check for tabs.

Comment: no, but with or without the result is the same

Comment: try without double quotes , and for spring boot 2. keep spring.liquibase.change-log

Comment: I have try, it didn't work. Liquibase seems to completely ignore application.yml

Comment: I'm not sure but if liquibase is not running at all try spring.liquibase.enabled=true

Comment: if you remove quotes and classpath prefix does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have found:

I was using this:

> spring.config.location=other.yml

whiche was working find in springboot1, but not anymore in springboot2

during the migration from spring-boot 1 to spring-boot 2, the behavior of the parameter spring.config.location ( where the application.yml- like file are) have change. (source:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide)

In springboot1,   spring.config.location=other.yml add to the default file application.yml other.yml file

In springboot2, spring.config.location replace the default application.yml file by the other.yml file.

To correct, I will need to do this:

> spring.config.location=application.yml,other.yml