# How can i use liquibase with spring cloud config server?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, liquibase, spring-cloud-config

I am currently trying to learn microservice architecture. I've been trying to develop a spring boot application. I've just implemented Config Server in my application. Before I implemented Config Server, liquibase was working fine with these properties.

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:/db.changelog-master.xml
```

After the implementation, my service doesn't found the db.changelog-master.xml file.
db.changelog directory is under my service resources. How should I change the "change-log" property?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312211/spring-boot-2-and-liquibase-config-in-application-yml-ignored) help?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the change-log property like this

```
change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

and I've inserted  `<include>**/*.xml</include>` in my root pom.xml file.

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.yml</include>
                    <include>**/*.json</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Now everything works fine.